# Plesk failed to start

Tags: plesk, dedicated-server

I'm having some problems restarting plesk on our server.

I increased the memory limit in our PHP.ini file and had stopped the server and was in the process of restarting when i've received the following error:

```
[root@server77-68-52-152 ~]# /etc/init.d/psa start
Starting xinetd service...                                           done
Starting named service...                                            done
Starting mysqld service...                                           done
Starting postgresql service...                                       done
Starting psa-spamassassin service...                                 done
Plesk: Starting Mail Server... already started
Starting mail handlers tmpfs storage
Starting Plesk...                                                    failed
Starting drwebd service...                                           failed
```

I'll be honest I'm very new to the dedicated server side of things so need all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an earlier SSL upgrade that broke plesk...it hadn't come to light because plesk hadn't been restarted until the point I updated the PHP file!

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the log files for the exact reason. It will help in fixing the issue faster.  Below the log files path of plesk. Check the reason there why plesk is failing to start.

Error log: /var/log/sw-cp-server/error_log

Access log: /usr/local/psa/admin/logs/httpsd_access_log

Panel log: /usr/local/psa/admin/logs/panel.log